# CSS and JQuery not working in Angular2 HostListener with IE 11 and Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, angular

Animated logo on bootstrap nav header is not working with IE 11 or Firefox but everything works great in Chrome and Opera.

Here is the listener in my components class:

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onWindowScroll() {
    let number = this.document.body.scrollTop;
if (number > 50) {
    $("#logobottom_container").hide('shrink');
    $("#logotop").fadeOut('slow').css({ "display":"none" });
    $("#logo").fadeIn('slow').css({ "display": "block" });
} else if (number < 54)  {
    $("#logobottom_container").show('slow');
    $("#logotop").fadeIn('slow').css({ "display": "block" });
    $("#logo").fadeOut('slow').css({ "display": "none" });
}
}
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#logo {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  margin: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
  display: none;
}

#logotop {
  float:left; 
  width: 150px;
  margin: 12px 55px 0px 55px;
  display: block;
}

#logobottom_container {
  width: 1080px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 53px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<a routerLink="/company" routerLinkActive="active">
  <img src="../assets/img/logo.png" alt="" id="logo">
  <img src="../assets/img/logotop.png" alt="" id="logotop">
</a>
```

Appreciate any insight into the issue.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue wasn't with the jquery or the css but with the way I was getting the number of pixels scrolled.

This is not cross browser compatible:
let number = this.document.body.scrollTop;

Use this instead:
let number = window.pageYOffset;